# How do I remove a directory in linux that has files and other directories as content

Tags: linux, shell, command-line, centos

Is there a speficic command or flag to remove all directories and files in a specific directory?

When I use `rm -r` I am able to remove all files found in a directory, but I am never able to remove the directories found in that directory.

Answer (score 1):

Add `-f` option:

```
rm -rf dirToNuke
```

---

Warning: This is a nuclear command.